# Resharper - Comment behind if-clause

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resharper

```
// What I want
if (condition) // explanation
{

}

// What I get
if (condition)
    // explanation
{

}
```

Do you know an option to reach this? Can't find something fitting in this scenario.

Comment: What option in Resharper are you using?

Comment: Mainly default options. I just switched back to VS IntelliSense.

Comment: I mean, what were you doing or what is it that you want to do? What does Resharper have to do with it? It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: is your condition too long?

Comment: @MuctadirDinar Haha, that's it! Don't know why I didn't see it. Thanks!

Comment: Still, it was guess work. Please state your questions more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably having a large `condition`. That is why resharper is putting your comment in the next line.